# How to find out the reason of a warning in Python?

Tags: python-2.7, debugging, pdb

I encountered the following warning when it runs `scipy.stats.stats.pearsonr()` in my program

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/stats/stats.py:2471: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
```

I wonder how to find out the reason of the warning, by using print out, or by using a debugger like pdb (I know something about pdb, but I don't know how to use pdb to find out the reason of the warning here).

Here is the line of my program that uses `pearsonr()`:

```
    ...
    corr = pearsonr(t1, t2)
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/warnings.html#testing-warnings), you can change the default warning behavior to raise an exception, which would of course make it much easier to track down and debug.

```
import warnings
# Cause all warnings to raise exceptions:
warnings.simplefilter("error")  # change the hook
# Trigger a warning:
corr = pearsonr(t1, t2)  # this will now raise
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace [`warnings.showwarning`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/warnings.html#warnings.showwarning) with a function that will [print the stack trace](https://docs.python.org/2/library/traceback.html#traceback.print_stack).

Comment: Thanks. (1) I didn't use `warnings.showwarning`. How will you use the function that will print the stack trace? (2) I use `corr = pearsonr(t1, t2)`  inside a loop, and the warning quoted in my post only happens at some iteration. and how can I catch the iteration when the warning happens?

Comment: Print each frame of the stack trace.

Comment: `corr = pearsonr(t1, t2)` is inside a loop, and the warning quoted in my post only happens at some iteration. and how can I catch the iteration when the warning happens? Or do you mean print each frame of the stack trace for every iteration?